# How to prove a theorem on natural numbers using Coq list

Tags: coq

I'm new in Coq. To do practice on list and list of pairs, I used Coq list library to prove a simple theorem of natural numbers. I try to prove the simple property of natural numbers:

```
forall n, multiplier, a0....an, d1...dn: 
((a0*multiplier)=d1)+((a1*multiplier)=d2)+((a2*multiplier)=d3)+...+((an*multiplier)=dn) = result 
        ->    (a0+a1+a2+...+an) * multiplier = d1+d2+...+dn = result
```

((3*2)=6)+((5*2)=10)+((9*2)=18) = 34 ->  (3+5+9)*2 = 6+10+18 = 34 can be an example of this property(i.e. n=3 and multiplier = 2).

I use list of pairs (storing a's in one list and d's in another list) to code this property in Coq as:

```
Require Import List.

Fixpoint addnumbers (L : list nat) : nat :=
  match L with
      | nil    => 0
      | H::tail => H + addnumbers tail
  end.

Theorem resultAreEqual : forall (natListofpair :list (nat * nat)) 
(multiplier : nat) (result : nat),
Forall (fun '(a,d) => a * multiplier = d ) natListofpair ->  
 addnumbers(List.map (@fst nat  nat) natListofpair) * multiplier = result   ->
  addnumbers (List.map (@snd nat  nat) natListofpair) = result.

Proof.
intros.
destruct natListofpair.
subst. simpl. reflexivity.
rewrite <- H0.
inversion H.
destruct p. simpl.
```

But I don't know how I should continue this prove. I'm stuck in this proving for one week. I'd be thankful for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason you are having difficulty is that you have stated your lemma in an indirect way.  When proving something in Coq, it is very important that you state it as simple as possible, as this often leads to easier proofs. In this case, the statement can become much simpler by using higher-order functions on lists.

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Definition sum (l : list nat) := fold_right Nat.add 0 l.

Lemma my_lemma l m : sum (map (Nat.mul m) l) = m * sum l.
```

The `sum` function is the equivalent of your `addnumbers`.  The lemma says "the result of multiplying all numbers in `l` by `m` and adding them is the same as the result of adding them up first and multiplying by `m` later".

To prove this result, we need a crucial ingredient that your proof was missing: *induction*. This is often needed in Coq when we want to reason about objects of unbounded size, such as lists.  Here is one possible proof.

```
Proof.
  unfold sum.
  induction l as [|x l IH]; simpl.
  - (* Nil case *)
    now rewrite Nat.mul_0_r.
  - (* Cons case *)
    now rewrite IH, Nat.mul_add_distr_l.
Qed.
```

Comment: You might not be able to define the same higher-order functions, which could make your proof more difficult. But you will still need induction in that case to get the proof to go through, probably.

Comment: Thank you Arthur. But what if the data type of the list wasn't of type list nat . I mean if there was no chance to use High order functions, for example due to using inductive data type and having my own operators rather than simple + or *, how should I manage to prove those one using the same strategy? I'm asking this question because I simplified the real problem I had in proving using list of pairs to this simple property over nat to learn the tactics I should use in proving my actual theorem. I still need the tactics over list of pairs, no other way.

Comment: I agree partially with @Arthur, the key to this proof is `induction`, the re-formulation using the `fold` higher-order function plays a minor role in this problem.

Comment: Arthur is the best.

Comment: @Arthur I have a confusing problem, please help me. In definition of Forall2  available in https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html, can I remove the constructor  Forall2_nill to make the nil case False ? I mean definining, for example, Forall3  only with the second constructor Forall2_cons of Forall2 definition is logically correct or not?.

Comment: @TomAnd. Without a base case, it won't be possible to prove that any list satisfies Forall2, and the predicate will be contradictory. You may want instead to leave the definition as it is and have a separate hypothesis asserting that the list is nonempty. (Next time, it may be better to post this as a separate question, so that people will be able to find it more easily later.)

Comment: Yes, For sure, You are still the best problem solver. Thank you.